# Problem creating ImageButton function to change when the item is highlighted as a favorite xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm creating a project using Xamarin and MVVM, and I wanted to know how to create a button where I will have a gray favorite image and when I click, I want to change it to a red favorite image, there are 2 different images.

[I wanted something like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeIIk.png)

I tried to use ImageButton,But I had difficulty creating the Command function in the Viewmodel:

```
<ImageButton
    Margin="0,0,0.5"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    Command="{Binding AddFavouriteCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
    HorizontalOptions="End">
    <ImageButton.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding ProductFavItem}"
            TargetType="ImageButton"
            Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="love_filled.png" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger
            Binding="{Binding ProductFavItem}"
            TargetType="ImageButton"
            Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="love_default.png" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </ImageButton.Triggers>
</ImageButton>
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried and explain what specific problem you had

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bool variable(e.g. `public bool IsFavourited`) to the Item model of your data list, and update the icon of the `ImageView` based on the value of the bool variable.

I achieved this on my side, you can refer to the following code:

**Item.cs**

```
  public class Item: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        bool _isFavourited;
        public bool IsFavourited
        {
            get => _isFavourited;
            set => SetProperty(ref _isFavourited, value);
        }


        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;
            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

   //add command AddFavouriteCommand
   public ICommand AddFavouriteCommand { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel() 
    { 
         Items =new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test1" });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test2" });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test3" });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test4" });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test5" });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "test6" });

        AddFavouriteCommand = new Command<Item>((item) =>
        {
            item.IsFavourited= !item.IsFavourited;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("---------> item " + item.Name + " is favourited or not: " + item.IsFavourited);
        });
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiListViewMVVMApp.ViewModels"
             x:Class="MauiListViewMVVMApp.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MyViewModel></viewmodels:MyViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>


    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{ Binding Items}" x:Name="mCollectionView"   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout  Margin="3"  HeightRequest="60">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" BackgroundColor="Gray" WidthRequest="100"/>

                        <ImageButton   Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                Command="{Binding  Path= BindingContext.AddFavouriteCommand,Source={Reference mCollectionView }}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  >

                            <ImageButton.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger
                                    Binding="{Binding IsFavourited}"
                                    TargetType="ImageButton"
                                    Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="love_filled.png" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <DataTrigger
                                    Binding="{Binding IsFavourited}"
                                    TargetType="ImageButton"
                                    Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="love_default.png" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </ImageButton.Triggers>
                        </ImageButton>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**Note:**

Here, we can use the following code to bind command `AddFavouriteCommand` on the view model.And the `mCollectionView` is the `x:Name` of current CollectionView.

```
<ImageButton  Command="{Binding  Path= BindingContext.AddFavouriteCommand,Source={Reference mCollectionView }}"  CommandParameter="{Binding .}"  >
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I'm going to try to link this with firebase, I still don't know how, but I'll figure it out, but I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Congrats. Happy coding... :)